# Showing success logout message on the redirected page

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, session

Righ now I'm making login/register form in Php and Bootstrap. I was looking for solution how to display success log out message in index.php after user will be redirected to main website from logout.php. I found few solution but I write something else and I'm curios is it correct? It's working and all messages displaying correctly. I'm new in Php so all advice are very welcome.

Code in logout.php:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['signed'])) {
header("Location: index.php");
exit();
} else {
$_SESSION['sign_out_success'] = "Sign out successful!";
header("Location: index.php");
exit();
}
```

Code in index.php:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['sign_out_success'] )) {
  $sign_out_success = $_SESSION['sign_out_success'];
  echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show"       role="alert">'.$sign_out_success.'
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button></div>';
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: The code seems correct , so what's the problem ?

Comment: if it has any conflict you can ask but what is this ?

Comment: I just wanted to know is it correct way to do it. Everybody using GET method to display logout message, but it doesn't look really nice for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there could be 2 ways.

- You are using session to store messages and it could be OK
- another method is to just add `index.php?error=signout` or `index.php?error=wrongpassword` and in index.php file you can use `$_GET`

You can do in both ways.